# Apache NiFi : custom properties file, read its properties dynamically

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use the "nifi.variable.registry.properties" in nifi.properties files to put my custom variables which will be used by my controller services. This is working fine for all the variables. 
My requirement that is there any way I can use this variable or a conf file supplied to this variable, to evaluate or run some script to derive the value of the property?

e.g.
nifi.variable.registry.properties=my_path/to_conf/conf.file

my_path/to_conf/conf.file contents:

```
db_user: <my_db_user>
db_password: <my_db_password>
```

.
.

Now, I don't want the password to be written as above. I need something like this:

```
db_password: <my_script_to_decode_pass_from_password_keyfile>
```

Basically, I have a keyfile and encrypted password, a *script* to decrypt it based on the key. I want to use that script (which can be run) as a value of this property. So whenever this variable is used in controller services, the said script will execute and decrypt the password and assign it to "db_password" and it will be used further.

If above is not possible; then can I give that script (what format of output?) as a value to "nifi.variable.registry.properties" directly, so it runs and evaluates the password?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it isn't possible to do what you are describing...

NiFi does have support for encrypted configuration, but currently it only supports encrypted properties in nifi.properties and a couple of other config files like login-identity-providers.xml:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#encrypted-passwords-in-configuration-files

It might be possible to extend this feature to encrypt values inside files specified with nifi.variable.registry.properties.

Comment: I agree. The best path forward for this would probably be a [feature request via the Apache NiFi JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI), so that such a use case could be supported in future versions of NiFi.